# MPI_REDUCE on parts of array

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have arrays defined in Fortran as follows:

```
integer,dimension(100)::a
integer,dimension(100)::partial_sum_a
```

I wanted to use MPI_REDUCE to sum only the values of `a` from indices `5` to `10` (i.e. a(5),...,a(10)) on root. How would I do that? Will the usage of:

```
MPI_Reduce(a(5:),partial_sum_a(5:),6,...)
```

be fine? Or do I have to use MPI_TYPE_VECTOR?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, given that an array slice with more than one element is an array as well, the usual usage of `MPI_Reduce` will work. Obviously, you need to make sure that all the arguments in the `MPI_Reduce` call are correct, i.e. `count` matching the number of elements in send buffer etc. Most often you can try these things yourself faster than it takes you to get an answer from people on the internet.

Comment: So no need for MPI_TYPE_VECTOR?

Comment: I used `MPI_Reduce` with array slices without using `MPI_TYPE_VECTOR`.

Comment: I did use with slices for small arrays, it was fine, but when I do it for larger arrays it acts very weird, i.e. not as expected.